# Is there a way to tell XCode to always display "Counterparts" in the Assistant editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Side-by-side .m and .h files are maybe my favorite thing about XCode 4. Of course, there's gotta be a catch: XCode switches to "Manual" sometimes, showing some other random .h file. Switching among tabs, I frequently start writing in a .h which isn't actually the right one. I usually notice this pretty quickly, but it's annoying.

Is there a way to tell Xcode to always display the 'Counterparts' view, i.e. the .h to whatever .m I have in the primary editor?

**EDIT**: My workaround is the wonderful hand-twisting shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, which brings up the counterpart whenever Xcode decides to get all cute and show some random other file.

Comment: Now that is some Homer-Simpson-fat-finger shortcut. Helpful though!

Comment: hand-twisting because you are using the wrong fingers... ring finger on shift, thumb on both CMD Option and index on Z. Just 3 fingers for 4 keys :)

Comment: @RubberDuck that is brilliant, I always just do Z with my right hand and the other three with my left... yours is like the proper fingering for a piano chord.

Comment: I play piano at a hobby level, this is why! 

Comment: *Awesome tip!* And what an awful shortcut - Apple must have a secret deal with chiropractors..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not currently, no. File an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com

FYI, my own experience with this annoyance is usually caused by accidental trackpad navigations while my pointer is over an assistant pane.